# What does the zeroth law of thermodynamics define? Thermal equilibrium or temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics

If zeroth law defines temperature what defines thermal equilibrium? Do we define thermal equilibrium first and then go on defining the temperature? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It defines thermal equilibrium, or more precisely it identifies thermal equilibrium as a transitive relation.

In principle there are a bunch of different temperature scales which are functions of our "absolute" positive scale and come from various measurement apparatuses that we might bring into thermal equilibrium with an object and then they give us back some number. Like, we might appreciate if those scales are *monotonically increasing* so that we never have heat flow from a "colder" body to a "hotter" body according to that scale, but that doesn't distinguish $T$ from $\sqrt{T}$ or $T^2$. In fact there's a decent argument that our "absolute" scale is actually $T = 1/C$ of some more fundamental "coldness" scale, which allows us to better understand what "negative temperatures" are (negative-absolute-$T$ temperatures turn out to be hotter than positive-$T$ temperatures, a fact which is more obvious when looking at coldness $C$).

Our absolute scale depends on the idea of a small-and-long ideal piston storing an ideal gas: changes in its $T$ then show up in the displacement of the piston length $x$ from what it would be if there were no gas in there at all, allowing us to measure temperature; the fact that it is small just means that it does not disturb the other object's temperature much when we take the measurement.

But the fact that this is a transitive relation is more primitive. It's what makes thermometers possible in the first place. Thermometers are only useful because when I measure two temperatures as the same, I know that if I bring those two into thermal contact, they won't exchange heat. Imagine if I were measuring the wrong thing, for example wetness: I could measure your hand as some temperature $T$ ("dry") and measure the stove at the same temperature $T$ (equally "dry") but placing your hand on the stove could still burn you: then this temperature measurement fails to tell you what you really wanted to know. If the zeroth law weren't there then we would be admitting that it's *impossible* to tell you what you really wanted to know. Thankfully, it's not.

Comment: "_It defines thermal equilibrium_" but it already assumes what thermal equilibrium is because it states "_If two systems, A and B, are each in equilibrium with a third body C, then they are also in equilibrium with each other._" Therefore it tacitly assumes what thermal equilibrium is.

Comment: Right, that's why I said "more precisely it *identifies* that thermal equilibrium is transitive." It does tacitly assume that you know some things about what we're talking about. But that's actually very common in physics and more broadly in science: early definitions of some phenomenon do not explain exactly what it is but just help us identify the phenomena that we're trying to explain. Thermal equilibrium is a phenomenon like, "we perceive that there is a phenomenon called heat flow, but that sometimes two systems can be in an equilibrium where heat *doesn't* flow between them."

Comment: Exactly. The key word is transitivity. Since thermal equilibrium is also reflexive and symmetric, thermal equilibrium is a well defined equivalence relation.

Comment: With that said, our present best understanding does indeed start from a totally different place. We first define the uncertainties that come about from our inability to fully measure a system, and define the energy of that system, and we get this measure of coldness as "how much does this uncertainty change as we increase the energy of the system, holding its volume and number of particles constant?" Then things in the process of becoming more uncertain share energy or don't, depending on these partial-derivatives: so this defines both a temperature scale and equilibrium simultaneously.